# How to update local web page if a server changes?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi setup where I have the user be able to change values on the Pi via a web interface or a hardware interface. Currently, I'm passing information from the web interface to the Pi via a JS `XMLHTTPRequest`, which goes to a `GPIO.php` file to edit values on the pi.

My question is, how can I update the user's webpage if the values on the Pi change via the hardware interface, **without** reloading the page?

Comment: websocket does it. http://www.perrygeo.com/raspberry-pi-real-time-sensor-plots-with-websocketd.html

Comment: @tasasaki Awesome, that looks really promising!